# Implementing Frequency Domain Convolution in MATLAB (Convolution Theorem)

Tags: matlab, fft, discrete-signals, convolution, ifft

I'm trying to prove convolution in time domain is same as multiplication in frequency domain but I'm not getting the same answer in matlab.

Here is the code:

[image: This is the image]

Comment: multiplication of DFTs is *circular* convolution, not the linear one.

Solution 1 : Try `cconv` : `cconv(a,b)`

Solution 2 : Try adding cyclic prefix to `a` for example. `aa=[a a]; conv(aa,b);` The result is `ifft(x.*y)` from the end of cyclic prefix, in this case since the index 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the length as well in your `fft` command.
The two signals are of length $5$ and their convolution is of length $5+5-1=9$. So use this instead:

```
a=[1 2 3 4 5];
b=[6 7 8 9 10];
x=fft(a,9);
y=fft(b,9);
ifft(x.*y)

ans =

Columns 1 through 8

6.0000   19.0000   40.0000   70.0000  110.0000  114.0000  106.0000   85.0000

Column 9

50.0000

conv(a,b)
ans =

 6    19    40    70   110   114   106    85    50
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man I've been struggling a lot for this.No one has even asked any question regarding this.